# How to Get User's Data outside of Builder in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, builder, kivymd

I'm beginner in python. I started to learn kivy (maybe kivymd) 4days ago. I learned something new everyday. But I can't find any anwser on my problem. which I'm gonna share with you.

Before learning kivy, I learned tkinter. And It's my current Fav and Easy GUI module.

In Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

def show_data():
      userdata=user_input.get()
      print('Your Data is: '+userdata)

root=Tk()
root.title('Stackoverflow Help')
root.geometry('400x400')

user_input_text=Label(root,text='Enter Some Data',font='arial 20')
user_input_text.pack(pady=40)

user_input=Entry(root,font='20')
user_input.pack(pady=10)

user_input_button=Button(root,text='Done',font='20',command=show_data)
user_input_button.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I can Print/Get User inputed data in a Def/Function with `idname.get()` Method.

But In Kivy:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size=(400,600)

please_help_me="""
MDScreen:

      MDLabel:
      
            text: 'Please Enter Some Data'
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.55}
            
      MDTextField:
      
            id:user_input
            hint_text: 'Type Here' #How Can I Print/Get User Data outside of builder?
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.44}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300
            
      MDRaisedButton:
      
            text:'Done'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.35}
"""

class HelpPleaseApp(MDApp):
      def build(self):
          main=Builder.load_string(please_help_me)
          return main
    
      # I wanna create a Function Here That Print User's Inputed data from builder's 'MDTextField'

HelpPleaseApp().run()
```

I want to Print the `MDTextField` Inputted Data while button pressed.I know `on_release: print(user_input.text)` can do it, but It is inside the builder string. I want to do in in a function under main class. I also created `id` for it. But don't know how to get the `MDTextField.text`/User inputted data in a function and print it out. I know you will tell me to google it, But I already searched about it on google and youtube. So, I Need Your kind help(pls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `on_release: app.show_user_input(user_input.text)` under `MDRaisedButton` section, then define `show_user_input()` inside `HelpPleaseApp`:

```py
please_help_me="""
MDScreen:
      MDLabel:

            text: 'Please Enter Some Data'
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.55}

      MDTextField:

            id:user_input
            hint_text: 'Type Here' #How Can I Print/Get User Data outside of builder?
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.44}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:300

      MDRaisedButton:

            text:'Done'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.35}
            on_release: app.show_user_input(user_input.text)
"""

class HelpPleaseApp(MDApp):
      def show_user_input(self, text):
          print(text)

      def build(self):
          main = Builder.load_string(please_help_me)
          return main
```

Comment: Can you answer [this kivy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375246/how-to-update-mdlabels-text-on-button-click-in-kivy) also??