# How to update MDLabel's Text on button click in kivy

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy, kivymd

I'm beginner in python(and also on kivy). I started to learning kivy(maybe `kivymd`) 4days ago. I learned basics of it. But I got some problems, Before learning kivy I learned `tkinter`. So I'm giving examples in tkinter which I wanna do with kivymd.

I tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def change_word():
      site_list=['Google','Yahoo','Microsoft','APKpure','APKMB','Stackoverflow','Bing']
      text=random.choice(site_list)
      button_text.config(text=text)
      button_text.update()


root=Tk()
root.title('Help Me')
root.geometry('400x400')

button_text=Label(root,text='Click the Button Below to Change This Text',font='arial 15')
button_text.pack(pady=40)

button=Button(root,text='Change It',font='arial 15',command=change_word)
button.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I can update `Label`/Text with a def/Function using `idname.config()` to edit text and `idname.update()` to update it.

And in Kivymd:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
import random
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size=(400,600)

please_anwser_this="""
MDScreen:
      MDLabel:
            id:text-update
            text:'Click The Button below to Change this text'
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
      MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
            text:'Change It'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            icon:'crop-rotate'
            on_press:
                  #What Command Should I type Here to Update 'text-update'/MDLabel's text?
"""

class AnsweredOrNot(MDApp):
      def build(self):
          builder=Builder.load_string(please_anwser_this)
          return builder
      
      def change_word(self): #What Parameters should I give after self?
            site_list=['Google','Yahoo','Microsoft','APKpure','APKMB','Stackoverflow','Bing']
            text=random.choice(site_list)


AnsweredOrNot().run()
```

I wanna update `MDLabel.text`/`text-update.text` with a function/def (Like tkinter/Any other way) while the button pressed. Can anyone Help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference text to the Label using ids

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
import random
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size=(400,600)

please_anwser_this="""
MDScreen:
      MDLabel:
            id:text_update
            text:'Click The Button below to Change this text'
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
      MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
            text:'Change It'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            icon:'crop-rotate'
            on_press:
                  app.change_word()
                  
"""

class AnsweredOrNot(MDApp):
      def build(self):
          builder=Builder.load_string(please_anwser_this)
          return builder
      
      def change_word(self): #What Parameters should I give after self?
            site_list=['Google','Yahoo','Microsoft','APKpure','APKMB','Stackoverflow','Bing']
            text=random.choice(site_list)
            self.root.ids.text_update.text=(text)
            


AnsweredOrNot().run()
```

I've changed Label id from `text-update` to `text_update`

Comment: Thanks Bro, No one told me about `ids` on youtube.